# Firebase download URL disappears with variable inside React.js render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage, render

In a part of the html I return inside React render function. The "stories" (which retrieves values from state before render) contains js objects with attributes including "url" and others. When logging the entire object and other attributes individually, they appear on the console but the "url" attribute doesn't. The url contains the firebase download url for an image and it exists outside of the render function when I fetch it to load it into state. But disappears after I get into render(). This is a snippet inside of the render().

```
     <div className="Storysubmain">
        {stories.map((story, idx) => {
          console.log(story);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(story));
          console.log(story.url);
          return (
            <div className="story" key={idx}>
              {story.image != null ?
                <div className="storyimagebox">
                  <a rel='noopener noreferrer' target='_blank' href={story.link}>
                    <img src={story.url} alt='Related view' />
                  </a>
                </div>
                : ""
              }
              <div className="storydetails">
                {story.khronos == null ?
                  "" : (
                    <span className="storykhronos">{story.khronos}</span>
                  )
                }
                <span className="storytitle">{story.title}</span>
                <p>{story.text}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Output in the console is as follows:

[image]

So, the object shows the "url" attribute as an object but not as a string. "url" is undefined when accessed individually. I don't know what's going on. And as a result I get an alternate view of the image. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you `console.log(JSON.stringify(story))` and include the updated code and its output in the question?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Updated it. It changed it into a string. The url is gone though.

Comment: Is it accessible from stories[idx].url ?

Comment: @TechySharnav yes, that doesn't work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `JSON.stringify` doesn't show the `url` that means that that value/property is added after you initially log the object, and Chrome's console is just updating the logged object with the new property.

Most likely the `url` is loaded asynchronously from somewhere, but we can't say where that is based on the code you shared. It doesn't matter anyway, as the solution is the same no matter where it happens: when you set the `url` on a story in the `stories` object, you also need to update the `stories` object in the state of your app, so that React know that it needs to update the UI for that object.

Comment: Thank you! I was updating the state only once at the end after I was done with the loop that did the update! Lesson learned.

Comment: Hi Frank, I was working on the same issue. I am fetching the downloadURL, passing it to the state by dispatching. My component re-renders and the container for the image appears but the image doesn't. In fact, when I try to manually copy the uploaded image's downloadURL and use it inside an image component(in React Native) the image doesn't show again. I would be very appreciated if you can assist. I'll share the code in the answer:)